# Howto use list command with inner join

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

```
Table 1
Doccode  |  Doc_status
CM0001          1
CM0002          0
CM0003          1

Table 2
Doccode  |  Vehicle
CM0001      bike-001
CM0001      car-003
CM0002      bike-028
CM0003      car-011
CM0003      car-777
```

i select data with list command on table2 only

```
select t2.doccode, list(vehicle, ', ')
from table2 t2
group by t2.doccode
```

above command it ok!!

But..i can't use it with inner join what's wrong with command below??

```
select
      t2.doccode, list(vehicle, ', '),
      t1.doc_status
from
      table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
      on t2.doccode = t1.doccode
group by
     t2.doccode
```

Comment: If you don't need `t1.doc_status` try removing it.

Comment: thank Edper but i want doc_status too. that the reason to inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just include it in the `group by`:

```
select t2.doccode, list(vehicle, ', '),
       t1.doc_status
from table2 t2 inner join
      table1 t1
     on t2.doccode = t1.doccode
group by t2.doccode, t1.doc_status;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `GROUP BY` with aggregate function in this case `LIST()` should include all the fields in the `GROUP BY`. So if you don't need the **doc_status** remove it, like:

```
select
  t2.doccode, list(vehicle, ', ')
from
  table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
  on t2.doccode = t1.doccode
group by
t2.doccode
```

If you really need **doc_status** try:

```
select t1.doccode, VehicleList, doc_status
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
select
  doccode, list(vehicle, ', ') as VehicleList
from  table2 
group by
doccode ) t2
ON t1.doccode = t2.doccode
```